# Adding setInterval to componentDidMount in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the state of a React component every 1000 ms. However, I tried doing `setInterval` on the `componentDidMount`, but with no luck. Currently I get two results in my `console.log`, the one is an empty state object in the constructor, and the other is the fetched object from the API. How do I update the state of the component every 1000 ms with setInterval?

This is my code:

```
let url = 'some-link-bla-bla';

class Basemap extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Scene style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} 
                    mapProperties={{ basemap: 'satellite' }} 
                    viewProperties={ this.state } />
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url)
            .then(d => d.json().then(function(d) {
                console.log(d);
            }))
            .then(d => function(d) {
                this.setState({
                  center: [
                      {latitude : d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + 
                      {longitude: d.iss_position.longitude}
                    ]
                })
            });
    }
}

export default Basemap;
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your attempt with `setInterval`. Your code has none

Comment: @IsaaK08, If you found the right solution here, set it as Accepted.

Answer (score 6):

I moved the call to the fetch method with in the getCenter method, which I will pass to setInterval function with in componentDidMount

- Call this.getCenter() before you set the interval. It will fetch immediately after mounting the component.
- Clear the interval with in componentWillUnmount. It will make sure you setInterval does not trigger any fetch request after unmounting the component.

  ```
  let url = 'some-link-bla-bla';

  class Basemap extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <Scene style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} 
                  mapProperties={{ basemap: 'satellite' }} 
                  viewProperties={ this.state } />
      );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      // Call this function so that it fetch first time right after mounting the component
      this.getCenter();

      // set Interval
      this.interval = setInterval(this.getCenter, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      // Clear the interval right before component unmount
      clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  getCenter = () => {
      fetch(url)
              .then(d => d.json().then(function(d) {
                  console.log(d);
              }))
              .then(d => function(d) {
                  this.setState({
                    center: [
                        {latitude : d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + 
                        {longitude: d.iss_position.longitude}
                      ]
                  })
              });
  }
  }

  export default Basemap;
  ```

Comment: This worked for me. Only had to change getCenter in the mount to this.getCenter()

Comment: setInterval only seems to fire once and then stop for me.

Answer (score 3):

Normally with React I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` the only counterpart is that you need to call it once the function ended.

```
let url = 'some-link-bla-bla';

class Basemap extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        console.log(this.state);
        this.intervalFunc = this.intervalFunc.bind(this); // Here
        this.timeout= this.timeout.bind(this); // Here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Scene style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} 
                    mapProperties={{ basemap: 'satellite' }} 
                    viewProperties={ this.state } />
        );
    }

    intervalFunc() {
        fetch(url)
            .then(d => d.json().then(function(d) {
                console.log(d);
            }))
            .then(d => function(d) {
                this.setState({
                  center: [
                      {latitude : d.iss_position.latitude} + ', ' + 
                      {longitude: d.iss_position.longitude}
                    ]
                })
                this.timeout(); // Here
            });
    }

    timeout() {
        this.setTimeout(intervalFunc, 1000); // Here
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timeout(); // Here
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like appropriate solution, but I get:

  Line 35:  'timeout' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 40:  'intervalFunc' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 44:  'timeout' is not defined       no-undef

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `this.timeout()`

Comment: Code changed, changed `setTimeout()` to `this.setTimeout()` on `timeout()`

Comment: Recursive timeout function. Neat stuff.

Comment: @JosephCho Why is it neat? What if the server-side returns an error, will you try requests endlessly until it gets working by magic? This way it only calls another timeout if the last was successfull. I'm not saying it's better than `setInterval` because it's not, `setInterval` was made for this cases. Just another way to do it.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to clear the inverval after unmount.

Comment: I just genuinely thought it was a clever. It was a compliment.

Comment: Need to check neat on the dictionary. Sorry