# ReactJS SetTimeout / setInterval

Tags: reactjs, next.js, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to get the following to reload every 30 seconds.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://example.com/json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result.data,
        });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error,
        });
      },
    );
}
```

I have tried to wrap it in `setInterval` but no success. I am wondering how do I make this into a function so I can reload it as need be.

Comment: I think your question is similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982244/adding-setinterval-to-componentdidmount-in-react

Comment: `componentDidMount` triggers only once in the render phase,
also, setState is async.

Comment: I think you can find the example in react document ==>https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest you is to take fetch function out of componentDidMount method. Write it inside a loadData() called function or whatever you want to name it. Then in loadData() function wrap your fetch logic with like
following.

```
const loadData = () => { 
setInterval(
async function(){
  //your fetch logic here with await
}, 30000);
}

componentDidMount() {
loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to fetch data every 30 sec after you enter in component and then stop this fetching on component exit:

```
               componentDidMount() {
                this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
                  fetch('https://example.com/json')
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(
                    (result) => {
                        this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result.data
                        });
                        
                    },
                    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
                    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
                    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
                    (error) => {
                        this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                        });
                    });
                 }, 30000);
               }

               componentWillUnmount() {    
                   clearInterval(this.myInterval);
               }
```

Should be enough.